# cancel varnish cache so that it goes to the backend on the homepage only

Tags: varnish

```
if (req.url == "/") {
  return(pass);
}
```

Does this allow us to cancel the varnish only on the homepage (ex: [www.prism.com](http://www.prism.com)) and not other pages like [www.prism.com/product](http://www.prism.com/product)?

I was thinking this would also work, but I am not sure, and is the above the better option?

```
if (req.url ~ "") {
  return(pass);
}
```

I just want it to skip caching on the homepage, because we're using it to set a cookie for all users. I need to modify the caching, because I realized some code for generating cookies didn't work during peak hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code is indeed to right way to bypass the cache on the homepage:

```
if (req.url == "/") {
    return(pass);
}
```

However, please consider the impact of such an action. The homepage is the point of entry for the majority of your users. Not being able to cache it will have a severe impact on your performance.

The question is: what kind of cookie are you setting on the homepage?

- Is this cookie really required?
- Could to cookie be synthesized and created by Varnish instead?
- Could the cookie be set by Javascript instead.

Please consider your options and try to look for a solution where your most important page is still cached.

As a side-effect, you'll need to write the necessary VCL to deal with the `Cookie` request header for incoming requests that are considered cacheable.